# jquery get selected values of multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have  this form ..

```
<form method="post" action=''>

    <select class="first">
       <option value="0">choose ...</option>
       <option value="1">Hello</option>
       <option value="3">It's</option>
    </select>

    <select class="second">
       <option value="0">choose ...</option>
       <option value="2">World</option>
       <option value="4">me</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" class="dest" value="" />

</form>
```

and would like to dynamically gather selected informations with jQuery, because I need to decide on the selected values ...

When you select specific combination of OPTION values (lets say Hello + World) it should add some value to INPUT.dest and lock it (disable from editing) ...

But I can't make it work ... What I have, is that on each change of each select (separately only) i can map the actual value

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".first").change(function () {        
        var option = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        $(".dest").val(option);
    });

    $(".second").change(function () {        
        var option2 = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        $(".dest").val(option2);
    });

  });
```

Here is the [live demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zojdnywL/42/)

Do you know what am I missing? I know it will be just a little thing .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generalize it and use one event listener, and then gather the combination and do whatever:

```
$("select").change(function () {        
    var first = $(".first").find("option:selected").val();
    var second = $(".second").find("option:selected").val();

    if(first == 1 && second == 2)
            $(".dest").val("Hello world").prop("disabled",true);
    else
         $(".dest").val("Something else").prop("disabled",false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cxx428af/3/

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for !!!! thank you.. will mark it as answer as soon as it will be possible (told me I can't mark it in 3 min) .. .thank you !!!